# How to add Android Design Support library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

[image]

How can I add compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0' in Android Studio?
I can not find it in Project Structure Dependencies.

I have just updated Android Support Library in SDK Manager to the lastest version.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.memetix:microsoft-translator-java-api:0.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..." >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image]

Comment: I see `com.android.support:design` in the "Choose Library Dependency" dialog launched from the Project Structure dialog in my Android Studio 1.5.1 installation.

Comment: But I dont see. I updated Android Support Library and restarted Android Studio. Didnt help

Comment: I have Android Studio 1.1.0. Maybe I should update Android Studio?

Comment: That is probably a good idea in general, let alone for this issue.